# How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?

Tags: powershell, wait, execution

I have a PowerShell 1.0 script to just open a bunch of applications. The first is a virtual machine and the others are development applications.  I want the virtual machine to finish booting before the rest of the applications are opened.

In bash I could just say `"cmd1 && cmd2"`

This is what I've got...

```
C:\Applications\VirtualBox\vboxmanage startvm superdooper
    &"C:\Applications\NetBeans 6.5\bin\netbeans.exe"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was asked long ago, but since answers here are kind of references, I may mention an up to date usage. With the current implementation of `PowerShell` (it's `7.2 LTS` as of writing) you can use `&&` as you would do in `Bash`.

> Conditionally execute the right-hand side pipeline based on the success of the left-hand side pipeline.
>
> ```
>    # If Get-Process successfully finds a process called notepad,
>    # Stop-Process -Name notepad is called
>    Get-Process notepad && Stop-Process -Name notepad
> ```

Further info on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#pipeline-chain-operators--and-)

Answer (score 465):

Normally, for internal commands PowerShell does wait before starting the next command.  One exception to this rule is external Windows subsystem based EXE.  The first trick is to pipeline to [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null) like so:

```
Notepad.exe | Out-Null
```

PowerShell will wait until the Notepad.exe process has been exited before continuing.  That is nifty but kind of subtle to pick up from reading the code.  You can also use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the `-Wait` parameter:

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

If you are using the PowerShell Community Extensions version it is:

```
$proc = Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Another option in PowerShell 2.0 is to use a [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs):

```
$job = Start-Job { invoke command here }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Comment: As a side note, if you need to pass multiple arguments with `-ArgumentList`, separate them with commas like `-ArgumentList /D=test,/S`.

Comment: Thank you for the simple "<path to exe> | Out-Null" solution!  The problem with "the Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait" method is that the PowerShell pauses until all child processes spawned by the parent are complete, even if the parent terminates before them.  This caused our setup program issues.

Comment: This is what I use to wait for a VM to start
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VmName
while((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VmName -Status | `
    select -ExpandProperty Statuses | `
    ?{ $_.Code -match "PowerState" } | `
    select -ExpandProperty DisplayStatus) -ne "VM running")
{
    Start-Sleep -s 2
}
Start-Sleep -s 5 ## Give the VM time to come up so it can accept remote requests

Comment: Sorry for zombie comment but in case anyone is trying to duplicate this for VMware, grab PowerCLI and use Wait-Tools or a do-while with Invoke-VMScript until you get the desired response.

Answer (score 65):

Besides using [`Start-Process -Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), piping the output of an executable will make Powershell wait. Depending on the need, I will typically pipe to [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null), [`Out-Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default), [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) or `Out-String -Stream`. [Here](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-o-is-for-output) is a long list of some other output options.

```
# Saving output as a string to a variable.
$output = ping.exe example.com | Out-String

# Filtering the output.
ping stackoverflow.com | where { $_ -match '^reply' }

# Using Start-Process affords the most control.
Start-Process -Wait SomeExecutable.com
```

I do miss the CMD/Bash style operators that you referenced (&, &&, ||). It
seems we have to be [more verbose with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2416662/80161).

Comment: Note that _no_ extra work is needed to execute _console_ applications synchronously - as in any shell, that is the default behavior. Piping to `Out-String` _changes the output_ to a _single, multi-line_ string, whereas PowerShell by default returns an _array of lines_. `Start-Process` should be avoided for console applications (unless you truly want to run them in a _new window_) because you won't be able to capture or redirect their output.

Answer (score 15):

Just use "Wait-process" :

```
"notepad","calc","wmplayer" | ForEach-Object {Start-Process $_} | Wait-Process ;dir
```

job is done

Comment: It doesn't work with PowerShell 7.1.4 (on Windows 10).

Comment: you need `-PassThru`, otherwise it won't wait

Answer (score 10):

If you use `Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait`

You can also use the `-PassThru` option to echo output.

Comment: Note that `-PassThru` doesn't echo _output_ (a non-console-application by definition won't produce console output), it outputs a `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance that represents the newly launched process, so you can examine its properties and wait for it to exit later.

Comment: Even -passthru doesn't capture the standardoutput or standarderror, but at least it has the exitcode.

Answer (score 8):

Some programs can't process output stream very well,  using pipe to `Out-Null` may not block it.
And `Start-Process` needs the `-ArgumentList` switch to pass arguments, not so convenient.
There is also another approach.

```
$exitCode = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start(<process>,<arguments>).WaitForExit(<timeout>)
```

Comment: how do multiple arguments work in that call? how are they delimited? how does one handle various nested string escaping? ty!

Comment: @AnneTheAgile [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx)  use space to separate the arguments, for char escaping use backslash

Comment: ty @ifree, I did get testcomplete to run that way! I used single quotes around the list of space delimited arguments.[1]; but now echo $exitcode=false, which wasn't my returncode from the process?     [1] $exitCode = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "c:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 10\Bin\TestComplete.exe" ,'"c:\Users\ME\Documents\TestComplete 10 Projects\hig4TestProject1\hig4TestProject1.pjs" /run /project:myProj/test:"KeywordTests|zTdd1_Good" /exit' ).WaitForExit(60)

Comment: Start-Process -Wait took a long time (like a minute) to return to script execution after closing the application. This took a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Including the option `-NoNewWindow` gives me an error: `Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.`

The only way I could get it to work was to call:

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -Wait
```

Comment: Usually means that it needs to run as admin.  Admin privilege escalation *needs* to open a new window. It's not possible to connect an Admin command to a non admin console.

Answer (score 4):

Building upon @Justin & @Nathan Hartley 's answers:

```
& "my.exe" | Out-Null    #go nowhere    
& "my.exe" | Out-Default # go to default destination  (e.g. console)
& "my.exe" | Out-String  # return a string
```

the piping will return it in real-time

```
& "my.exe" | %{    
   if ($_ -match 'OK')    
   { Write-Host $_ -f Green }    
   else if ($_ -match 'FAIL|ERROR')   
   { Write-Host $_ -f Red }   
   else    
   { Write-Host $_ }    
}
```

**Note: If the executed program returns anything other than a 0 exitcode, the piping will not work. You can force it to pipe with [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) such as `2>&1`**

```
& "my.exe" 2>&1 | Out-String
```

sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7272390/254276

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/b6691fba-0e92-4e9d-aec2-47f3d5a17419/start-process-and-redirect-output-to-powershell-window

Answer (score 2):

Taking it further you could even parse on the fly

e.g.

```
& "my.exe" | %{
    if ($_ -match 'OK')
    { Write-Host $_ -f Green }
    else if ($_ -match 'FAIL|ERROR')
    { Write-Host $_ -f Red }
    else 
    { Write-Host $_ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always cmd.

```
cmd /c start /wait notepad
```

Or

```
notepad | out-host
```

Here's another odd one.  Start-process keeps waiting for notepad, even though the 2nd powershell exits.  ("cmd /c start /wait powershell notepad" doesn't do this.)  So even if anything in the process tree runs in the background (the NSIS uninstaller does this), it still waits.

```
start-process -wait powershell notepad
```