# How to pipe all output of .exe execution in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, output

In Powershell I am running `psftp.exe` which is PuTTy's homepage. I am doing this:

```
$cmd = "psftp.exe"
$args = '"username@ssh"@ftp.domain.com -b psftp.txt';
$output = & $cmd $args
```

This works; and I am printing out `$output`. But it only catches some output in that variable (like "Remote working directory is [...]") and is throwing other output to an error type like this:

```
psftp.exe : Using username "username@ssh".
At C:\full_script.ps1:37 char:20
+         $output = & <<<<  $cmd $args
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Using username "username@ssh".:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

This "Using username ..." etc looks like a normal FTP message. How can I make sure all output gets put into `$output`?

Comment: If you have to use the call operator (&), (which you don't if directly running psftp), the args have to be an array, like `'user@domain','-b','file.txt'`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is some output is being sent to STDERR and redirection works differently in PowerShell than in CMD.EXE.

[How to redirect output of console program to a file in PowerShell](http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2010/03/how-to-redirect-output-of-console-program-to-a-file-in-powershell/) has a good description of the problem and a clever workaround.

Basically, call `CMD` with your executable as a parameter. Like this:

### UPDATE

I fixed my code so it would actually work.  :)

```
$args = '"username@ssh"@ftp.domain.com -b psftp.txt';
$output = cmd /c psftp.exe $args 2`>`&1
```

Comment: No quotes around the $cmd details? I tried this, but the Powershell just seems to hang now.

Comment: Thanks, that somewhat worked as it didn't parse any output into an STDERR. But instead of the "Using username ..." etc now being in `$output`, it seems nowhere to be found. With your code, did you intend for that?

Comment: I didn't have `PSFTP.EXE` to test with so I was using `PSEXEC.EXE` and `$args = '-d'` to test. I'll see if I can try it with `PSFTP`.

Comment: I should add that I was using `PSEXEC` because I know it writes some of it's output to STDERR.

Comment: Actually I may be mistaken; I think the STDERR is there. But appears at the end of the $output string. Intended?

Comment: It should capture it in the order it is output. Where does it appear if you just run your command from the prompt without redirecting or capturing the output to a variable?

Comment: If you use cmd /c, it all goes to standard output anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Give this a try

```
$output = [string] (& psftp.exe 'username@ssh@ftp.domain.com' -b psftp.txt 2>&1)
```

There is a PowerShell [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/765551/in-powershell-v3-you-cant-redirect-stderr-to-stdout-without-generating-error-records) about `2>&1` making error records. The `[string]` cast works around it.

Comment: Can't get this to work in PowerShell 2.0. It redirects to a file named `1`.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

```
& "my.exe" | Out-Null    #go nowhere    
& "my.exe" | Out-Default # go to default destination  (e.g. console)
& "my.exe" | Out-String  # return a string
```

the piping will return it in real-time

```
& "my.exe" | %{    
   if ($_ -match 'OK')    
   { Write-Host $_ -f Green }    
   else if ($_ -match 'FAIL|ERROR')   
   { Write-Host $_ -f Red }   
   else    
   { Write-Host $_ }    
}
```

**Note:
If the executed program returns anything other than a 0 exitcode, the piping will not work. You can force it to pipe with [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) such as `2>&1`**

```
& "my.exe" 2>&1 | Out-String
```

sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7272390/254276

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/b6691fba-0e92-4e9d-aec2-47f3d5a17419/start-process-and-redirect-output-to-powershell-window