# How to prevent stderr from being handled by powershell

Tags: powershell, caffe, stderr

I am using powershell for running an executable file(`caffe.exe`). The output is provided by `glog`, which is written to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. So, if I redirect `stderr` to a log file:

```
$ARGUMENT_LIST = "train", "--solver=cnn.prototxt"
& caffe.exe "$ARGUMENT_LIST" 2> caffe.log
```

log file would be like this:

```
caffe.exe : I0512 15:46:58.838964  1124 caffe.cpp:218] Using GPUs 0
所在位置 D:\caffe\cnn\train_cnn.ps1:13 字符: 1
+ & $BIN_PATH $ARGUMENT_LIST 2>&1 > $LOG_FILE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (I0512 15:46:58....8] Using GPUs 0:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I0512 15:46:59.014129  1124 caffe.cpp:223] GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1060
...
```

I have to remove these additional lines manually.
I tried to use `$ErrorView = "CategoryView"`, but still at least one line at the front:

```
NotSpecified: (I0512 15:55:24....8] Using GPUs 0:String) [], RemoteException
```

It seems that the first line from `stderr` has been handled by powershell.
Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437244/how-to-pipe-all-output-of-exe-execution-in-powershell