# how to redirect output of application in command window, which started with affinity?

Tags: powershell, window, windows-console

the following command starts the C++ application in new command window with process affinity set to 0xF.

```
start /affinity F test.ext arg1 arg2
```

But the above command opens a new cmd window and closes immediately when test.exe ends. I tried the following to get output but it doesn't do anything.

```
start /affinity F test.ext arg1 arg2 ^> out.txt
```

I appreciate if you know how to do this on powershell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)

> The PowerShell redirection operators are as follows, where n
>   represents the stream number. The Success stream ( 1 ) is the default
>   if no stream is specified.
>
> Operator  Description
>   Syntax

```
>           Send specified stream to a file.                        n>
>>          Append specified stream to a file.                      n>>
>&1         Redirects the specified stream to the Success stream.   n>&1


# Examples
# Example 1: Redirect errors and output to a file

dir 'C:\', 'fakepath' 2>&1 > .\dir.log
```

> This example runs dir on one item that will succeed, and one that will
>   error.
>
> It uses 2>&1 to redirect the Error stream to the Success stream, and >
>   to send the resultant Success stream to a file called dir.log

```
# Example 2: Send all Success stream data to a file

.\script.ps1 > script.log
```

> This command sends all Success stream data to a file called script.log

***Also, a possible duplicate of the following***

[How to pipe all output of .exe execution in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437244/how-to-pipe-all-output-of-exe-execution-in-powershell)

[How to redirect the output of a PowerShell to a file during its execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215260/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-powershell-to-a-file-during-its-execution)

***See also***

> Running external commands, can or will require special
>   consideration.
>
> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right)
>
> - [Part 1](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
> - [Part 2](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-2)
> - [Part 3](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-3)
>
> [Quoting specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules%20https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)