# How to add like a loop or if else statement to do the task 1 by 1

Tags: powershell, software-distribution, sccm

I want to add a task sequence, meaning the script will wait the first task to be finished first, then proceed with next task. If task receives error, it will not proceed and probably will create log for that.

```
WindowsSensor_F7C855810C3B47FC8931D2E5E9E889BF-57.exe /install /quiet /norestart

"%ProgramFiles%\CrowdStrike\CSInstallGuard.exe" PW="nzhHLfrpy5rqTFVsne8D"

if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Cylance\Desktop\CylanceSvc.exe" msiexec /x {2E64FC5C-9286-4A31-916B-0D8AE4B22954} /qn /norestart
```

Below is the code I come out. Can someone clean it up

```
Start-Process "WindowsSensor_F7C855810C3B47FC8931D2E5E9E889BF-57.exe" /install /quiet /norestart | Out-null

Start-Process "%ProgramFiles%\CrowdStrike\CSInstallGuard.exe" PW="nzhHLfrpy5rqTFVsne8D" | Out-null



if (test-path %ProgramFiles%\Cylance\Desktop\CylanceSvc.exe .PathType leaf){
    msiexec /x {2E64FC5C-9286-4A31-916B-0D8AE4B22954} /qn /norestart | Out-null
    }

    else {
    break

    }
```

Comment: Use the `-Wait` switch on `Start-Process` so the code only continues when the task is done. Use `$env:ProgramFiles` instead of `%ProgramFiles%` and combine the path's to use with [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6). To run the msiexec with arguments, there are lots of examples to be found like for instance [this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72405a6c-068e-4f7a-9989-dd3db63d5da9/how-to-add-these-arguments-in-msiexec-to-run?forum=winserverpowershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe output like
`WindowsSensor_F7C855810C3B47FC8931D2E5E9E889BF-57.exe /install /quiet /norestart | Out-null`
This will make powershell to wait for the command to finish.

... actually I just retyped your question in the search bur and found similar ones with great answers, for example look at 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next).

Comment: Hi. I have edited the code. Can you check it at my main question. thx

Comment: Your are mixing two alternative methods: either use  | out-null of Start-process with -wait option, but not both