# How to make Start-Process with Run as administrator should wait till finish

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

i am having a code shown below. When i execute this code i want start-Process should wait. Once it is executed i will be accessing th exit code through $process. But here it is not working properly.

```
$process=Start-Process  powershell -Verb runAs "$exePath ${args} "  #Run as administrator
 Write-Output "hello world"
 Write-Output $process.exitCode
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

Comment: If you have problems with a command you should first look at its documentation and check the available options the command has. in this case you simply need "-wait -passthru" (docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-4.0)

Comment: How to pass these arguments when we are  using -Verb runas.  If you see my example i am using Runas to execute elevated permission. Can you please suggest me with my example.