# How do I make a function can work in sequence?

Tags: function, powershell

I have a powershell script with some function. But I can not figure it out to make it work sequencely. Anyone can help me to arrange it?
    #Get Date and time
    $Timestamp = get-date -Format yyyy-mm-dd

```
#Get the processor architecture
$Get_PA = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")

if($Get_PA = "AMD64"){
$Path = "X:\CUSTOM\ODM\ODMIC\AMD64"}
else
{$Path = "X:\CUSTOM\ODM\ODMIC\AMD64\X86"}

#Get Information from uber.ini
$Get_MAC         = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini UnitInformation MACAddress FE_MAC FE_MAC.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_MAC        = Get-Content .\FE_MAC.CMD
$a_MAC,$b_MAC    = $Read_MAC -split "="

$Get_SN          = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini UnitInformation SerialNumber FE_SN FE_SN.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_SN         = Get-Content .\FE_SN.CMD
$a_SN,$b_SN       = $Read_SN -split "="

$Get_IP       = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini FILESERVER0 IP FE_IP FE_IP.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_IP         = Get-Content .\FE_IP.CMD
$a_IP,$b_IP = $Read_IP -split "="

$Get_netuser  = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini FILESERVER0 netuser FE_netuser FE_netuser.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_netuser = Get-Content .\FE_netuser.CMD
$a_netuser,$b_netuser = $Read_netuser -split "="

$Get_netpass  = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini FILESERVER0 netpass FE_netpass FE_netpass.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_netpass  = Get-Content .\FE_netpass.CMD
$a_netpass,$b_netpass = $Read_netpass -split "="

$Get_UBStage  = & $Path\UIni.exe X:\uber.ini State downloadstage FE_UBStage FE_UBStage.CMD
start-sleep -s 1
$Read_UBStage   = Get-Content .\FE_UBStage.CMD
$a_UBStage,$b_UBStage = $Read_UBStage -split "="


#-----CNT_PRISM-----#

#Connect to PRISM
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\$b_IP\TempRepository\BPSAutoGM", $False, "$b_netuser", "$b_netpass")
start-sleep -s 5

#Create Working Folder if not exist
$WKFD = "$b_SN-$b_MAC"
$WKFD_Path = "P:\Logs\$WKFD"
if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($WKFD_Path ))
{
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $WKFD_Path
}

$FE_ODMIC_WKFD = $WKFD_Path


#Backup Uber.ini
Copy-Item -Path X:\uber.ini -Destination "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\$b_SN-$Timestamp-$b_UBStage-ODMIC_UBER.INI"


#-----CHK_TOAST-----#
#-----TOAST-----#
Function TOAST
{
#Delete Toast Flag
if(Test-Path -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\$b_SN-Toast.flg"){
    Remove-Item "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\$b_SN-Toast.flg"
}

#Copy logs ot working folder
Copy-Item -Path .\BPSFE_ODMIC.log -Destination "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\$b_SN-$Timestamp-ODMIC_Toast_FEWDTTST.log"

#Toast
$Path_Toast = "X:\Tools\WinToast\"
$Run_Toast         = & $Path_Toast\WinToast.exe /U /PHSA /NA
start-sleep -s 3

#Disconnect to PRISM
& net use P: /delete /yes
start-sleep -s 3
& net use Q: /delete /yes
start-sleep -s 3

#Reboot
Restart-Computer

}

#Check for Toast flag
if(Test-Path -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\$b_SN-Toast.flg")
{
    #GOTO TOAST#
    TOAST
}
else
{
"Toast flag not found"
}
#-------------------------------------------------------------#

#Auto GM Selection
Function Call_GUI
{
#Run GUI to choose AutoGM
& .\run_gui_1.cmd
start-Sleep -s 1 
$Log = Get-Content .\log.txt | Where-Object {$_.Contains("600")}

if(
    ($Log) -and 
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM")) -and 
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\JOB")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\POfile")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\AutoGM.flg"))
){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\JOB"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\POfile"
        New-Item -ItemType File -Force -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\AutoGM.flg"

    CHK_GM_STAGE

} 
else 
{
    END_Proc
}
}


#-----AUTOGM_SELECT-----#
Function AUTOGM_SELECT
{
#Manually GM or Auto GM selection GUI
if(Test-Path -Path "$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\AutoGM.flg")
{
    CHK_GM_STAGE
}

else
{
    Call_GUI
}
}

#-----GET_DASH_MODE-----#
#Get DASH Mode
$Get_SKU = & $Path\BiosConfigUtility.exe /getvalue:"SKU Number" | Where-Object {$_.Contains("@ODM@GM")}
if($Get_SKU)
{
$MLGM2ODM = "1"
    AUTOGM_SELECT
}
else
{
    END_Proc
}

Function CHK_GM_STAGE
{
#AUTO GM 

if($MLGM2ODM -eq "1" -and $b_UBStage -eq "101")
{ 
    GM_BEGIN
}

if($MLGM2ODM -eq "1" -and $b_UBStage -eq "444")
{ 
    GM_END
}

else
{
    END_Proc
}
}

#-----GM_BEGIN-----#
Function GM_BEGIN
{
& .\2_GUI_Default_Folder.ps1
}
#-----CHK_GM_STAGE-----#


#-----GM_END-----#
Function GM_END
{

}

#-----END_PROCESS-----#
Function END_Proc
{
#Copy logs ot working folder

#Disconnect to PRISM
& net use P: /delete /yes
start-sleep -s 3
& net use Q: /delete /yes
start-sleep -s 3

}
```

I tried this code, but it does not work sequencely, so some function do not work. How do I arrange it well, help me please. Thank you.

Comment: what is `UIni.exe`? also, why are you getting the info [ip, mac, etc.] from that utility instead of the usual CIM/WMI cmdlets?

Comment: Its complicated to explain it. My question just want to arrange the function correctly

Comment: There is quite a lot of code here. Most of which has little to do with display / arranging the data. Can you show an example of how it currently looks and what you want it to look like? there is several issues here but first thing I noticed is `![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_ODMIC_WKFD\AUTOGM\AutoGM.flg")` you create the file if it does not exist however the test is if its a directory.

Comment: Also your `if` command is not a comparison but an assignment, as the assignment isn't empty it will ***always*** return true and thus `$path` will always be `"X:\CUSTOM\ODM\ODMIC\AMD64"`. Read [about_comparison_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @Job - if what you want is to run the steps in sequence, take a look at this ... How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next

Answer (score 1):

As Lee_Dailey suggested [*grin*], use `Start-Process -Wait` to run the external programs:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "<exe>" -ArgumentList @(arg1,arg2) -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying UIni runs in the background?  That would be strange if it outputs text.  Piping it to Write-Output might be the less painful way to go, to make powershell wait.  And if you used the full path to UIni, you wouldn't need '&'.