# Powershell start-process argumentlist not treating colon correctly

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to run the following code snippet:

`start-process -Filepath "c:\support\mbbr.exe" -ArgumentList 'register','–key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE' -Wait -NoNewWindow`

However it stops processing the argument at the colon as it treats it as a reserved character. When I try to escape it with `, it treats the escape character as a normal character and won't let me escape:

```
Error: –key is an invalid option.

The syntax of register command is:

  register [-key:<prodkey>]
```

I'm out of ideas, anyone got any clues?

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion "it treats it as a reserved character"? (When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work.)

Comment: Updated original post with current result.

Comment: Does it work if you use `& "c:\support\mbbr.exe" register "-key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE"` ?

Comment: I don't suppose this would work?  `c:\support\mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE`

Comment: Using & returns the same error.

Comment: Same thing with js2010's command. `./mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE` works fine though.

Comment: I would recommend deleting the above comment if it is not correct (you say here it works fine, but later you say it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Run it directly seems simplest:

```
c:\support\mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE
```

For waiting, this may be less annoying:

```
cmd /c start /wait c:\support\mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE
```

There's lots of tricks to make powershell wait:  [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the -wait flag in order to run followup commands. Can't have them run asynch.

Comment: Problem with cmd is that it still pops up a window while I need it to run hidden.

Comment: That link has various other ways to wait, like `| out-null`.  Maybe you should update the question saying you want to wait, but don't want a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Run with invoke-expression and use the 'cmd /c' to catch it when it returns:

```
invoke-expression "cmd /c c:\support\mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE"
```

if you have to run it on remote machines, you'll need to use invoke-command:

```
invoke-command -computername <remote_hostname> -scriptblock {cmd /c c:\support\mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE}
```

HTH

Comment: Same issue here, cmd opens a window and I need to run hidden.

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is not necessary in this case (and in fact, [not recommended](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)).

Answer (score 0):

As you noted in your comment, this command should work:

```
C:\support\mbbr.exe register -key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE
```

If the path and/or filename to `mbbr.exe` contains spaces, use the invocation/call operator (`&`):

```
& "C:\Program Files\blah\mbbr.exe" register -key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE
```

You shouldn't need `Start-Process` or `cmd.exe`.

Since it seems that `mbbr.exe` still gives an error with the above commands, try quoting its `-key` argument, as follows:

```
C:\support\mbbr.exe register "-key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE"
```

or this way:

```
C:\support\mbbr.exe register -key:"ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE"
```

If those commands do not work, it may be that the help message from the executable is incorrect (we can't help with that as we don't have your executable).

Comment: After re-testing, `./mbbr.exe register –key:ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE-ABCDE` seems to give me the same error of it not listening to the argument after and including the colon.