# How to wait for an elevated PowerShell process to exit when launched in a C# .NET project?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following function in C#:

```cs
public static void RunPowerShellScriptFromElevatedPowerShell(string strPowerShellScriptFileName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Running powershell script from elevation: {strPowerShellScriptFileName}");

    string strCallPowerShellCommand = "powershell.exe";
    string command = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File {CDataAccess.Instance.ReadLocalParam(CDataAccess.ELocalParamList.E_SCRIPT_REPO_PATH)}\\{strPowerShellScriptFileName} {CDataAccess.Instance.ReadLocalParam(CDataAccess.ELocalParamList.E_SCRIPT_REPO_PATH)}";
    Process process = Process.Start("powershell", $"cd '{CDataAccess.Instance.ReadLocalParam(CDataAccess.ELocalParamList.E_MANIFEST_REPO_PATH)}';Start-Process {strCallPowerShellCommand} '{command}' -Verb runAs");    // taken from https://superuser.com/a/812902/1065771

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

When I run this function the code continues even though the power shell script is still running. How can I get this to work so that the code waits until the elevated powershell instance closes?

Note: I don't think this is a duplicate of [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next) because in that question (and all the others I could find on StackOverflow) the powershell process is NOT in elevated shell. In this case it is which makes it slightly more different. I knew about those other questions and they didn't help me. I really think you shouldn't mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Why are you calling a PowerShell command to start a process, rather than starting the process yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp

Comment: What is that process doing?  It may be that the process is actually ending but is spawing other processes that continue running.  Your code looks fine at a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is the PowerShell script file being invoked via the `-File` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, that  performs the elevation, presumably via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs`.

To make *that* call synchronous, add `-Wait` to it.

To get the process exit code from that call, add `-PassThru` and query the `.ExitCode` property of the process-information object ([`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)) that is returned
(`$exitCode = (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait ...).ExitCode`)