Trying to install .net 8 sdk with invoke-command vs enter-pssession
I'm trying to install .Net 8 sdk remotely. The Invoke-Command didn't work for me with the script below. However, the Enter-PSSession did work in an interactive session.
What is the reason for the different behaviour?
Invoke-Command
invoke-command -computername Server1 {
  c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.301-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart
}  

Enter-PSSession
PS C:\temp> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\blah\Documents> c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.301-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\blah\Documents>


There's many ways to wait for a command to finish.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next Or use new-pssession with invoke-command.


Most likely, your c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.301-win-x64.exe application is a GUI-subsystem application, which PowerShell executes asynchronously; that is, it launches the application, but doesn't wait for its completion.
By using Invoke-Command with a -ComputerName argument rather than via an explicitly created session object (via New-PSSession) passed to the -Session parameter, you're creating a session implicitly that exists only for the duration of the Invoke-Command call, whereas a session entered interactively with Enter-PSSession stays open until you manually exit it.
When a session is closed, any still running processes in it are automatically terminated.
Thus, if your installer hasn't completed yet (which is very likely, given the asynchronous nature of the call), it will be forcefully terminated.
The simplest solution is to make the call synchronous, which is most easily accomplished by piping to Out-Null:[1]
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 {
  c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.301-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart | Out-Null
}

Note that this will also make Invoke-Command wait until the installation completes.
If that is undesired, you can use the -AsJob switch to instantly return a job object that you can query later for completion of the remote installation.

[1] Simply piping the call to another cmdlet implicitly makes PowerShell wait for the call to complete. This technique also makes PowerShell reflect the call's process exit code in the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.
