Does the PowerShell call operator `&` wait for a command to finish?
We are using the call operator & to run an executable in an automated process:
& $pathToExecutable

Now it seems like PowerShell does not inherently wait for this executable to finish and continues script execution, leading to a failure of our automated process in some use cases. Does the call operator not wait for the started process to finish, or does it only wait under certain conditions or for a specific type of commands?
The documentation of the call operator does not mention if it waits or not, it simply says the command runs in a child scope. I feel like by default you would expect that it runs the command in a synchronous way and executes the next line once this command is finished.

EDIT(thanks @js2020 ):
It depends on the executible.
for example cmd.exe does wait while notepad.exe does not.
write-host 1
& cmd.exe /c timeout 5
write-host 2

write-host 3
& notepad.exe $PROFILE
write-host 4

ORIGINAL:
It waits.
try
write-host 1
& cmd.exe /c timeout 5
write-host 2



Thanks for your response with a clear example. Upvoted. From the observed behavior with our executable, I am a 100% sure that it does not wait in certain circumstances (or certain versions?). Do you know about that?

No, sorry. Without knowing what executible and the code you are talking about I can only make the hypothesis the exe spawns independent child-processes so the main exe concludes its run while everything else keeps running.   Evaliate using Start-process as it has a -Wait parameter that might work for you

I am using Start-process and -Wait now, that is how I discovered that the call operator & does not seem to await my executable and that is what made me ask this question. So it seems like the executable is getting properly awaited by Start-process and -Wait and not by the call operator. The executable is a third party, I sadly do not know what processes it spawns.

Cannot help you, sorry. I suggest to open a new question asking why sometimes & does not wait

It's cmd that waits, not &.  & notepad for a counterexample.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next

@js2010 thanks. Well, it fits the "it depends on the executible" but that is not in the answer... should I delete it?

Maybe you can add it as a remark to the question, then it is clear. You answered the question correctly.

I think the & notepad vs Start-Process -Wait notepad vs Start-Process notepad is actually a really good example to see the behavior. It shows a clear difference to & cmd.exe /c timeout 5 and Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5", where Start-Process seems to wait even without the -Wait parameter. It looks like & only waits if the process can be executed in the current scope or child scope?

@sirtao Let your conscience be your guide.

cmd always waits:  cmd /c notepad.  start -wait waits for child processes too, even if the parent process quits.  It's good for the free NSIS uninstaller (firefix, etc).

Thank you guys for the clarifications. You helped me to fully understand our bug.
